# Can i create a selection box with google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way how i can create a selection box when running a script in google sheets?   I already have a code up and running however i want the user to select a month from a list that will appear.  The list of the months are already in one of the sheets.  I then want the month that the user selects to be 'stored' in a cell.   Is this doable?

IF anyone would like to help.  assume that the list of months are in an array in cell range A1 to A10 in a worksheet called 'Summary'.  and i would like the month that the users selects to be 'stored' in cell B10 in the worksheet 'Summary'

Comment: It would be nice if you can put a screenshot to help people to understand your question better.

Comment: What do you mean by selection box? (many people use a cell data validation for this) Do you want to create a custom dialog? Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?